# Can You Block Search Terms

Tags: magento-1.8, search, search-terms

We keep getting search terms relating to an **SQL Injection**. It is definitely a bot because it is the exact same keywords week on week.

Is there anyway to maybe see the IP where these bots are coming from and block them? I keep deleting the terms from the backend but it is becoming tedious.

An example search term is something line: `bed jcb 1=1` or `beNCHMaRK(MD5,5555555555)`

Our website is fully patched and we have restricted the amount of letters which can be entered in our search.

Thanks you.

Our magento version is 1.8.1.0

Answer (score 3):

FishPig has this NoBots module which I've used before and it does work
https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/extensions/block-robots-stop-spam/
hope it helps